# import 'react-native-gesture-handler' raises an error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build my first React Native app using React Navigation. I installed all dependencies following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/juanpablogdl/86c7db533280f5fd23735794d870a38c), but as soon as I add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` to **app.js**, I get the following error:

```
info Reloading app...
[Fri Sep 04 2020 01:33:50.990]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js: Cannot find module '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/cinetogoproject/mobile/cinetogo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js'
[Fri Sep 04 2020 01:34:47.390]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js: Cannot find module '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/cinetogoproject/mobile/cinetogo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js'
```

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: can you add a little more code,

Comment: please reinstall react-native-gesture-handler